# Нужно ли разбивать файлы по директориям

Tags: linux, сервер

Как лучше организовать хранение большого количества изображений на сервере сайта (на `linux`)? Можно ли их все складывать в одну директорию или лучше разложить по разным? Будет ли при этом какая-то разница в скорости доступа к ним? Речь идет о десятках тысяч файлов.

Comment: Если открывать файл по известному имени, а не, например, читать и сортировать список всего каталога для поиска в нём файла по условию, то, вроде бы, сейчас на xfs и на ext4 нет особых тормозов при нескольких тысячах файлов в каталоге. Тем не менее, я бы сначала проверил элементарной сишной программой, сколько времени у вас будет занимать тысяча open()'ов по заранее сформированному списку (а хоть и по формируемому чтением каталога) в каталоге с тысячей файлов и со ста тысячами.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev спасибо

Comment: в разложении по папкам есть один большой-большой плюс - когда захочется разделить хранилище на два сервера, то это будет сделать очень легко.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делай структуру каталогов, как у сквида или как у браузеров. Рекомендую брать хеш от имени, резать его на части и создавать каталоги. Несмотря на то что несколько тысяч файлов в каталоге ищется быстро, этот поиск блокирует сервер. При высоких частотах может быть лишняя нагрузка.

Опять же оптимизация это дело такое, что начинать с 1% вещей не стоит. Но если сделать каталоги не осложнит логику - можно и сделать.

Статья на тему 
https://m.habr.com/ru/post/227855/

Comment: Кстати, есть прикольный скрипт `renrot`, который помимо этого, ещё кучу полезных вещей умеет делать с каталогами изображений (и не только).